# Table with a numbered list

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

What is the best way to make a table/list that looks like this:

```
1. Item 1
        subitem      type    date
        subitem      type    date

2. Item 2
        subitem      type    date
        subitem      type    date
...
```

The subitems, types and dates should be aligned. I'm using the `article` document class with no special fonts.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Not sure I understand about the `subitems`.

Comment: In case you are looking for it, I have deleted my earlier answer as it contained an extra level of list nesting that is not needed since you are not numbering the sub items, in which case @GonzaloMedina's solution is cleaner.

Comment: I noticed that you have received answers to your questions but you haven't accepted any of them; please consider doing so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use the standard `enumerate` and `tabular` environments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1 \par
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabular}
  \item Item 2 \par
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabular}
  \item Item 3 \par
  \begin{tabular}{p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}p{0.25\linewidth}}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option, if you want automatic calculation for the column width, would be to use the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1 \par
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \item Item 2 \par
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \item Item 3 \par
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XXX}
    subitem & type & date \\
    subitem & type & date \\
  \end{tabularx}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, it would be better to put `\newenvironment{mysubitem}{\begin{tabularx}{XXX}}{\end{tabularx}}` in your preamble and use `\begin{mysubitem}` instead of `\begin{tabularx}{XXX}` and `\end{mysubitem}` instead of `\end{tabularx}`. Becuase if you will have later wanted to change the spacing or whatever, you only modify your definition of `mysubitem` instead of changing all occurences or `tabularx`.