# Enumerated List and Table

Tags: tables, lists, enumerate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Table with a numbered list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48050/table-with-a-numbered-list)

How to I create an enumerated list with tables enbedded in each item:

Item 1 Descriptipon

```
     Col1    Col2    Col3
     Col1    Col2    Col3
```

Item 2 Description

```
     Col1    Col2    Col3
     Col1    Col2    Col3
```

I would like all Col1 entries (that is across Items) to be aligned. Same for Col2 and Col3 entries.

Comment: I suppose I could always manually set a certain column width, but I was hoping to span the with the width of the page using {\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}lcl}

Comment: @AlexRichter: I merged the two accounts together now.