# Making the table enumerated

Tags: tables, lists

I don't know LaTeX very well, and I don't know the proper words in LaTeX commands for my question, so I was going to ask it here.
You know in the problem pages of mathematics books, where they have a question like:

> 5. Solve these equations
>
>    (a) eq 1 (b) eq 2 (c) eq 3
>      (d) eq 4 (e) eq 5 (f) eq 6

How do you do that in LaTeX?

Yes, I have tried searching but [Enumerated List and Table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48050/table-with-a-numbered-list) is not what I want.
I want it to look like the problem page in a math book.

This is the code I came up with:

```
\begin{enumerate}
%question <<Question 6 page 68 Pure Mathematics 1>>>
\item Solve the following inequalities. 
  \begin{enumerate} 
    \begin{tabular}{ l c r }
     \item $ \dfrac{1}{3}\left(8x+1 \right) - 2\left(x-3 \right) > 10$ &\item  $\dfrac{5}{2}\left( x+1\right) - 2\left(x-3\right) <7 $ & \item $\dfrac{2x+1}{3} - \dfrac{4x+5}{2} \le 0 $ \\
     \item $\dfrac{3x-2}{2} - \dfrac{x-4}{3} < x $ & \item $ \dfrac{x+1}{4} + \dfrac{1}{6} \ge \dfrac{2x-5}{3}$ & \item $\dfrac{x}{2} - \dfrac{3-2x}{5} \le 5$ \\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you don't need the equations aligned then you should  us `enumerate*` from [the `enumitem` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem), which produces results similar to `inparaenum`, but provides more flexibility.

[image]

However, if you want them aligned, the `array` (since it is entirely math content) environment, or `tabular` is the solution to use:

[image]

### Notes:

- I have used a `\newcolumntype` from [the `array` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) to simplify the use of the `array` or `tabular` environments in adding the labels.
- Also see [What are the differences between using paralist vs. enumitem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18411/what-are-the-differences-between-using-paralist-vs-enumitem)

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}% {enumerate*}
\usepackage{array}%            \newcolumntype

\newcounter{Label}
\newcommand*{\AddLabel}{\stepcounter{Label}(\alph{Label})~}%
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\AddLabel}l<{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Solve these equations (enumerate*):

\noindent
\begin{enumerate*}
\item $x+3=7$ \item $x^2+5x-7=0$ \item $3x^4+5x^2-6x+7=0$
\item $az^2+bx+c=0$ \item $\sin x +\cos x =0$ \item $\cos x =-1$
\end{enumerate*}

\item Solve these equations (array):

\noindent
$\begin{array}{RRR}
 x+3=7       & x^2+5x-7=0        & 3x^4+5x^2-6x+7=0 \\
 az^2+bx+c=0 & \sin x +\cos x =0 & \cos x =1
\end{array}$

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Above and beyond, and thanks for the code, so I can have them line up.

Answer (score 9):

The `paralist` package allows this. For your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}

\item Solve these equations:

\begin{inparaenum}
\item eq 1 \item eq 2 \item eq 3\\
\item eq 4 \item eq 5 \item eq 6
\end{inparaenum}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

You will probably want to insert some horizontal spacing after the content of each of the items.

Comment: I'd use `\hfil` between each item to get some horizontal spacing.