# rounded corners using the framed package

Tags: framed, rounded-corners

Is it possible to create a frame, using the `framed` package, with rounded corners? I know for a fact that there are other packages such as the `mdframed` package but what I am looking for is an application only using the `framed` package.

EDIT

---

After looking at the answer below, I created the following environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{test}{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\ovalbox}
\MakeFramed{\advance\hsize-\width\FrameRestore}}
{\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{test}
\end{document}
```

The only problem is that it shouts out a warning:

```
\oval, \circle, or \line size unavailable
```

Why?

PS. I did not want to post another question so just edited this one.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not `mdframed`?

Comment: @cmhughes That is a good question! I already know how to do it using the `mdframed` package. Its a challenge I have not overcomed.

Answer (score 4):

I am afraid that `framed` package cannot do that alone. But you can redefine `\fbox` or `\FrameCommand` to obtain this results with the usual command `\fbox` or the `framed` environment.

This need some complex TeX definitions that are already included  in `fancybox.sty`. So, the most simple solution in to load also `fancybox` package and then make a very simple definitions including `\ovalbox` or `\Ovalbox`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox,framed}
\renewcommand\fbox[1]{\Ovalbox{#1}}
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{\ovalbox}
\begin{document}
Some text 
\begin{framed}
A framed environment example ...
\end{framed}
Some text
\vspace{2cm}
Some text 
\fbox{Simple framed box} 
Some text 
\end{document}
```

But I think that is more clear, more intuitive and less problematic use `\Ovalbox` or `\ovalbox` directly and left `\fbox` for rentangular boxes.

---

About colors asked in azetina comment, as far I now `fancybox` do not have color options, but is not difficult to obtain a colored border. See [Enumerate over two columns in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71562/enumerate-over-two-columns-in-tabular-environment) for a example. A colored background seem more complicated (for me), so my advise is left definitively `\fbox` and `fancybox` and use the `tcolorbox` or `mdframed` packages, both excellent alternatives with many interesting options. There are a lot examples here, just some are in:

- [Beamer tables like block structure look-and-feel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74197/beamer-tables-like-block-structure-look-and-feel)
- [tcolorbox - list of listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86711/tcolorbox-list-of-listings).
- [Vertically centre the title in mdframed](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/89775/vertically-centre-the-title-in-mdframed)

Comment: Can you add color to the rule and the inside of the oval box?

Comment: @azetina, I updated the answer