# How to enumerate with two columns inside a box?

Tags: align, enumerate, box, fbox, varwidth

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a enumerated list with two columns inside a box with minimal waste of space. The code outputs the first items of each column unaligned among themselves and produces a lot of empty space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\begin{document}
    \framebox{\begin{varwidth}{3in}
        \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Banana
                \item Apple
                \item Orange
                \item Strawberry
                \item Grape
                \item Tomato
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \end{varwidth}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Enumerate with two columns inside a framebox]

Comment: welcome -- see the answer below using `itemize` and `minipage` -- you can adapt the same for `enumerate` and `minipage` --the `0.2\linewidth` lays down the width of the column as a percentage of the linewidth

Comment: What's the purpose of using a `varwidth` environment? Why not use a `minipage` environment?

Comment: The `\framebox` was getting a missing `\item` and improper `\prevdepth` without it or with any other cases (such as when I tried putting the list inside a `\framebox` with `minipage`). It was the only "solution" that worked at the time haha. Thanks, Mico!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With double `minipage` environment

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
    \item item 1
    \item item 2
    \item item 3
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
    \item item 4
    \item item 5
    \item item 6
\end{minipage}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

**With single minipage environment** --

[Enumerate over two columns in tabular environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71562/enumerate-over-two-columns-in-tabular-environment)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
        \begin{enumerate}
            \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
            \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
            \begin{multicols}{2}
                \item Time Limit Waved
                \item Exam/Sep Location
                \item Questions Read Aloud
                \item Answers Any Way
                \item Calc/Abacus Permitted
                \item On-Task Focusing Prompts
                \item Waive Spelling Reqs
                \item Revise Test Format 
                \item Revise Test Directions 
                \item Breaks 
            \end{multicols}
        \end{enumerate}
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Using a single `minipage` environment (of length `0.4\linewidth`, say) will do as well.

Comment: thanks for the heads up -- just edited and added

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer! I've used a \fbox with the single minipage environment and it worked like a charm! I had a lot of trouble with other cases (such as the double minipage environment) because the console would claim a missing item or depth error. I'm really thankful for you answer and everyone else in the thread. Thanks again, guys!